# A game in which players do not have the same information

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I would like to model situation in which one player has more information that other ones.

Answers, books and articles are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: That is way too broad a question!  In fact, it's not a question at all.  Here's such a game.  Three players sit in separate rooms.  The first player to guess $92$ wins.  Player 1 is told to guess a number.   Player2 isn't told anything. And Player 3 is told to guess $92$.   So Player 1: guesses $17$.  Player 2: sits in the room and waits.  Player 3: guesses $92$.  Player 3 wins.

Comment: Google for "Bayesian Nash equilibrium", which is the standard equilibrium concept for simultaneous games with asymmetric information. There are literally thousands of examples out there.